# NSInvocation get target causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsinvocation

I have a weird problem with `NSInvocation`. I'm using it as a return callback when a network operation completes. Let me explain the previous sentence in more detail:

I'm using a custom made network protocol which works over a TCP socket and I have a class which uses this protocol and serves as a connection to my server. Now the class has a method lets say `performNetworkRequestWithDelegate:` which is implemented like so:

```
- (void)performNetworkRequestWithDelegate:(id<MyClassDelegate>)delegate
{
    NSString *requestKey = [self randomUniqueString];
    id request = [self assembleRequestAndSoOnAndSoForth];
    [request setKey:requestKey];

    SEL method = @selector(callbackStatusCode:response:error:);
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [delegate methodSignatureForSelector:method];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    invocation.target = delegate;
    invocation.selector = method;

    delegateInvocationMap[requestKey] = invocation; //See below for an explanation what the delegateInvocationMap is

    [self sendRequest:request];
}
```

Okay so I know there are some things that need to be explained. First don't bother about anything related to the request except the `requestKey`. It works like so: the request key gets looped back to me when I get a response from the server. So its like setting a HTTP header field which gets looped back to you when you get a response from the server. That way I can identify which request was made. The `delegateInvocationMap` is a `NSMutableDictionary` which holds on to our invocations and we can get the correct one when we get the response and parse out the `requestKey`.

Now the handler for the response is like this:

```
- (void)processResponse:(id)response
{
    //Check for errors and whatnot

    NSString *requestKey = [response requestKey];
    if (!requestKey) return; //This never happens and is handled more correctly but keep it like this for the sake of simplicity

    NSInvocation *invocation = delegateInvocationMap[requestKey];
    if (!invocation) return; 

    [delegateInvocationMap removeObjectForKey:requestKey];

    if (!invocation.target) return; //THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM

    [self setInvocationReturnParams:invocation fromResponse:response];
    [invocation invoke]; //This works when everything is fine
}
```

This function also works when there is a successful response return or when there are any errors I handle them correctly. Except one:

When the target of the invocation is dealloced I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to check if there is a target for my invocation. The apple docs say:

`The receiver’s target, or nil if the receiver has no target.`

How can I check if the receiver was already deallocated? This is a huge pain.

**EDIT:** In the comments below I found that accessing a deallocated object is always unknown behaviour. I don't know if there is any official documentation specifying this (I didn't check yet) but I have a workaround idea. Would it be possible to observe the target of the invocation for a dealloc call via KVO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSInvocation`'s `target` property is not an ARC `weak` reference; it is defined as `assign`. If you do not hold any references to this object, it will be deallocated and you will start seeing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exceptions.

```
@property(assign) id target
```

ARC automatically converts `assign` properties to `unsafe_unretained` instead of `weak`. A `weak` property will be set to `nil` when the object is deallocated; an `unsafe_unretained` property will continue pointing at the memory address, which will be garbage.

You can get around this by using the `retainArguments` method.

```
[invocation retainArguments];
```

From the documentation:

> If the receiver hasn’t already done so, retains the target and all object arguments of the receiver and copies all of its C-string arguments and blocks.

Comment: I do not want the invocation to maintain a strong reference since those references are references to view controllers most of the time. I want to check if the object the invocation is targeting still exists and if not I just want to "forget the whole thing".

Comment: And you're sure it's specifically `target` that's giving you the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? Accessing any other property on `invocation` at that same line is fine?

Comment: This was an excellent point but I'm afraid that other things seem to work fine.  

I tried logging the selector using `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(invocation.selector));` and it works perfectly fine. I used this log statement just before the `if (!invocation.target)`.

Comment: So an `NSLog(@"%@", invocation.target);` also causes the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

Comment: It's not `weak` (as in ARC zeroing weak references). It's just plain not memory managed, which is called `unsafe_unretained` in ARC.

Comment: @Majster: There is no way to check whether an object still exists; it is undefined behavior to do anything to a deallocated object in any way. You must hold a strong reference to something, and if that thing is no longer used (e.g. no longer shown on screen), then calling something on it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you, cal you please provide a link with more on this topic? I will have to hold a strong reference to it as it seems yes. I do have a question if I could make a workaround, something like KVO when the object gets released and then remove my invocation from the dictionary, how's that? Any other ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? I can't seem to figure out a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Since NSInvocation wants to retain the target, but you essentially want it to keep a weak reference, use something like [TPDWeakProxy](https://github.com/trussworks/TPDWeakProxy). The proxy takes a reference and holds it with a weak pointer, but the proxy can be held strongly.

Here's how I did it in OCMockito in an NSInvocation category method:

```
- (void)mkt_retainArgumentsWithWeakTarget
{
    if (self.argumentsRetained)
        return;
    TPDWeakProxy *proxy = [[TPDWeakProxy alloc] initWithObject:self.target];
    self.target = proxy;
    [self retainArguments];
}
```

This replaces the target with what's essentially a weak target.